# Keep track of ast.Walk() parsing errors in Go

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a custom parser and would like to keep track of errors I come across. How do I keep track of errors during parsing without using a global variable when doing a `ast.Walk`?

```
type visitor struct {
    err error
}

func (v visitor) Visit(n ast.Node) ast.Visitor {
    switch d := n.(type) {
    case *ast.BinaryExpr:
        if d.Op != token.LAND {
            v.err = fmt.Errorf("Illegal operator :%s", d.Op) // NOT WORKING
                return v
        }
    }
    return v
}
```

I use the above code as:-

```
var v visitor
ast.Walk(v, astTree)
```

This probably doesn't work as, in `func (v visitor)`, v is not a pointer to struct. What's the recommended way of keeping track of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collecting the errors in a struct is a good approach, but you need to use a pointer receiver to make it work.

```
func (v *visitor) Visit(n ast.Node) ast.Visitor {  // change to pointer receiver
     ...
}

...

var v visitor
ast.Walk(&v, astTree) // pass pointer to visitor
```

Comment: Oops, `type visitor` is an interface, all it really wants is "something"  that has the method `Visit`. Hence, a pointer can be passed too. Thank you @ThunderCat.